# MySQL different behaviour on windows and linux

Tags: mysql

I've this little SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE `aaaa` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`text` varchar(100),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `aaaa` (`text`) VALUES (NULL);

ALTER TABLE `aaaa` CHANGE `text` `text` TEXT NOT NULL;
```

It fails when trying on MySQL 5.5 on Windows 7 with error "Data truncated for column 'text' at row 1" but works on MySQL 5.5 on Debian.

**Why is the behaviour different?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably configured to run in different [SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html). Compare the results of:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

on both servers.

Comment: You're right! Windows machine showd `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` and linuh machine returns an empty string. I'll look into it further.

Answer (score 1):

I see consistent behavior both on Windows

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `aaaa` CHANGE `text` `text` TEXT NOT NULL;
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'text' at row 1
```

and on Mac OS X

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `aaaa` CHANGE `text` `text` TEXT NOT NULL;
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'text' at row 1
```

In your case you may have different `sql_mode` settings for Windows and Debian installations of MySQL.

Comment: You're right. :-) I've selected @rsanchez answer as accepted because it contains the needed SQL.